# compact set boundary condition prove

Tags: real-analysis

the question is:

> Prove that a set E ⊂ R is open if and only if E is not contains any of its boundary points.

I'm kind of not sure with good enough(?) proof... so please look at my several approach and fixed it. and if you have your own proof please let me know

1. E is an open but it does not contains all its boundary points. 
   E is open so define the E as
                    E = (a,b]
   at point b it as the b+ϵ, so it does not contains all its boundary points. 
   so  'E is an open but it does not contains all its boundary points. ' assumption is      contradicted

Answer (score 1):

Forward: Pick any point $p \in E$. Since $E$ is open, you can put an open neighborhood around $p$ contained entirely in $E$; so $p$ is not in the boundary of $E$. Because $p \in E$ was arbitrary, the desired conclusion follows.

Reverse (contrapositive): $E$ contains some boundary point $b$. Then you can't put an open neighborhood around $b \in E$; so $E$ is not open.

Answer (score 0):

$BdE=\overline E-intE=\overline E \cap \overline {(\Bbb R-E)}$ and $BdE\cap intE=\emptyset$. If $E$ is open then $intE=E$ and thus $BdE\cap E=\emptyset$.

Now if $BdE\cap E=\emptyset$ then $E\cap \overline E \cap \overline {(\Bbb R-E)}= E \cap \overline {(\Bbb R-E)}=\emptyset$. Thus $E\subset \Bbb R-\overline {(\Bbb R-E)}=intE$ and so $E=int E$

Comment: @Jake Eum ,check my proof please.thank you